# Oracle SQL statement to Linq Not working

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

I  have a query that I need to have it converted in SQL. Been searching on doing this for some time now but nothing is successful 
here is the  ORACLE query

```
SELECT 
     DRKY AS REASON_CODE,
     DRDL01 AS DESCRIPTION
 FROM shema.SourceTable
WHERE drsy = '00'  AND DRDL01 IS NOT NULL AND (drrt = 'W4' OR drrt = 'W5') and NVL ( trim(DRKY), '000') = '801';
```

This is my Linq query that does not return value

```
            var RJDEReasonCode = from a in JTable.SourceTable
                             where
                               a.DRSY.Equals( "00") &&
                               a.DRDL01 != null &&
                               (a.DRRT.Equals( "W4") ||
                               a.DRRT.Equals( "W5")) &&
                               a.DRKY.Equals( "801") // here is where the problem is  tried many things  but nothing has worked so far.
                             select new
                             {
                                 CATEGORY_CODE = a.DRRT,
                                 REASON_CODE = a.DRKY,
                                 DESCRIPTION = a.DRDL01
                             };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to trim `DRKY`:

```
a.DRKY.Trim() == "801"
```

Or possibly:

```
a.DRKY != null && a.DRKY.Trim() == "801"
```

(Personally I find `==` for string comparisons to be simpler than using `Equals`, but YMMV.)

Comment: +1 I also like using == more than Equals :P, and also I think this is the cause of the problem

Comment: I have another query that return a set of code and I want to plug them inplace of 801 , How can I do that ? here  is my first query  that return a result that is have used bind to  gridview  var RCode = from a in DbEntity.MobileAssetDowntimeReasonCodes where a.MobileAssetCategoryId.Equals(reasonCode) select new { a.JdeReasonCode };
            ReasonCode.DataSource = RCode.ToList();
            ReasonCode.DataBind(); need to use RCode values  instead of  801

Comment: @user2315840: It's not really clear what you mean, but I suggest you ask a new (appropriately detailed) question. You may well want to use a join instead...

Comment: @john i have asked another question can you look at it and see what i am doing wrong