# Linq to SQL query SubQuery

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

I have a follow up question on the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599757/oracle-sql-statement-to-linq-not-working/17599789?noredirect=1#17599789)

here are all of my Linq query

This is query 1:

```
var RCode = from a in DbEntity.MobileAssetDowntimeReasonCodes 
            where a.MobileAssetCategoryId.Equals(reasonCode) 
            select new 
            { 
                a.JdeReasonCode 
            };

ReasonCode.DataSource = RCode.ToList();
ReasonCode.DataBind();
```

this brings a resulting codes that are displayed in DataGrid.

here is  Query 2  which also works

```
var RJDEReasonCode = from a in JDETable.F0005
                                 where
                                   a.DRSY.Equals("00") &&
                                   a.DRDL01 != null &&
                                   (a.DRRT.Equals("W4") ||
                                   a.DRRT.Equals("W5")) &&
                                   a.DRKY.Trim() == "801"
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     CATEGORY_CODE = a.DRRT,
                                     REASON_CODE = a.DRKY,
                                     DESCRIPTION = a.DRDL01
                                 };
```

But instead of hardcoding "801" I want to pass the result of the query1 to query 2 and display query 2 results in my dataGrid.  how do I do that ?

Comment: Does query #1 return `801`? Try `a.DRKY.Trim() == RCode.FirstorDefault().JdeReasonCode`

Comment: query one returns a list of codes   such as  801 , 802,803 and I want to run each code  in the second query to get the details of that code and display that

Comment: You could do that in a loop, and concatenate the results of each iteration to a single collection. Or you could modify your LINQ statement to be something similar to: `RCode.Contains(a.DRKY.Trim())`

Comment: Have a read of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456606/1466627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List<string> RCode = DbEntity.MobileAssetDowntimeReasonCodes
    .Where(a=>a.MobileAssetCategoryID.Equals(reasonCode))
    .Select(a=>a.JdeReasonCode).ToList();

var RJDEReasonCode = JDETable.F0005
    .Where(a=>a.DRSY.Equals("00") && a.DRDL01 != null &&
             (a.DRRT.Equals("W4") || a.DRRT.Equals("W5")) &&
              RCode.Any(code => code.Contains(a.DRKY.Trim())))
    .Select(a=>new { CATEGORY_CODE = a.DRRT,
                     REASON_CODE = a.DRKY,
                     DESCRIPTION = a.DRDL01
    });
```

Uses the [Enumerable.Any Method](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx&ei=PwvfUc30Oa7E4APG9IHgAw&usg=AFQjCNERt-YUCjvX7NBW5SWBaAnElKbDOA&sig2=FDWnldkWgcj9_hj_wE7EGQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg) to check if the retrieved RCodes are one of the codes in your F0005 table.

Comment: Syntax is missing something .Select(a=>a.JdeReasonCode).ToList()); and .Select(a=>new { CATEGORY_CODE = a.DRRT, shows  error it says  'bool' does not contain a definition for 'select' and no extension method ..

Comment: @user2315840 Sorry, I was missing a bracket on each one.

Comment: this Worked.  Thanks  So much learning Linq is an wonderful experience.

Comment: @user2315840 Gotta start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

```
var RJDEReasonCode = from a in JDETable.F0005
                     where
                         a.DRSY.Equals("00") &&
                         a.DRDL01 != null &&
                         (a.DRRT.Equals("W4") ||
                         a.DRRT.Equals("W5")) &&
                         //and use it checking if it contains a.DRKY.Trim() 
                         RCode.Contains(a.DRKY.Trim())
                      select new
                      {
                                     CATEGORY_CODE = a.DRRT,
                                     REASON_CODE = a.DRKY,
                                     DESCRIPTION = a.DRDL01
                      };
```

Comment: can you elaborate  your answer a bit.  I am not understanding  this as I am new to Linq

Comment: Does not work  it says Contains has some invalid argument and  second error says Argument1: connot convert from 'string to ' anonymoustype#1'

Comment: what type is `JdeReasonCode`

Comment: JdeReasonCode  shows  linq type lines when i put break point on it